# Function tracing using Frida Stalker on Android

Tags: android, frida

I am attempting to trace all Java functions called in an Android application using Frida, but I'm encountering some challenges.

I have already looked into tracing functions by hooking all the application's functions (using `class.function.implementation = function(...parameters) {}`), but this becomes impractical for mid-sized applications due to scalability issues.

I came across Frida's Stalker API. I know that tracing native functions using Stalker is possible, therefore tried the following code snippet:

```js
var threads = Process.enumerateThreadsSync();
threads.forEach(function (thread) {
    Stalker.follow(thread.id,{
        events: { call: true },
        onReceive: function (events) {
            var calls = Stalker.parse(events, { annotate: false });
            calls.forEach(function (event) {
                var location = event[0];
                var target = event[1];
                var locationName = DebugSymbol.fromAddress(location).name;
                var targetName = DebugSymbol.fromAddress(target).name;
                console.log(locationName + " " + targetName);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

However, I am facing two issues:

(1) The app crashes shortly after it is started (maybe because I "stalk" all threads, including the one Frida runs on?)
(2) No Java methods are logged.

My main question is: **Is tracing Java functions generally not possible using Frida's Stalker API, or am I missing something in my approach?**

Comment: I am not sure if tracing all functions is a realistic scenario as it will extremely slow down the app execution. Don't forget that a simple app can execute a few thousand functions per second, just transferring all the trace data via USB or network will cause a lot of CPU resources and network bandwidth. And then there is the additional trace code which has to be executed. So be prepared to have a slow down factor of may be 1000 or even more so a simple app start can take an hour. BTW for tracing Java calls I would use `frida-trace`.